# Converting InputStreamReader into String

Tags: java, string, sockets, heap-memory, inputstream

Is there a better way to read Strings from an InputStreamReader.
In the Profiler im am getting a memory heap there.

```
public String getClientMessage() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(tempSocket.getInputStream()));     
    char[] buffer = new char[200];
    return new String(buffer, 0, bufferedReader.read(buffer));
}
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
[image]

EDIT:
Messages are sent with this:

```
public void sendServerMessage(String action) throws IOException{
    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(tempSocket.getOutputStream()));
    printWriter.print(action);
    printWriter.flush();
}
```

Comment: You're "getting a memory heap" ? What does it means ?

Comment: I don't see any problems in your screenshot, unless you are executing getClientMessage too much by accident.

Comment: I am executing getClientMessage every one second

Comment: Well, Dear, we don't know how those methods are interleaved which each other, so it could be more deep problem.

Comment: This is so interesting: you read some value from `tempSocket` and write it back to `tempSocket`. Some kind of `echo` service, yes?

Comment: These are two different classes, but I named them the same. Server sends a command, client sends a message.
But i am trying to do this, without the char array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use IOUtils, but it is easy to write if you can't use that library.

```
public String getClientMessage() throws IOException {
    Reader r = new InputStreamReader(tempSocket.getInputStream());
    char[] buffer = new char[4096];
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int len; (len = r.read(buffer)) > 0;)
         sb.append(buffer, 0, len);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

I suspect the problem is you have no way of know from the way you send messages when a message stops. This means you must read until you close the connection which you are not doing. If you don't want to wait until you close you need to add some way of knowing when a message is finished e.g. a newline.

```
// create this once per socket.
final PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(
      new OutputStreamWriter(tempSocket.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"), true);

public void sendServerMessage(String action) {
    // assuming there is no newlines in the message
    printWriter.println(action);  // auto flushed.
}

// create this once per socket
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(tempSocket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));     

public String getClientMessage() throws IOException {
     // read until the end of a line, which is the end of a message.
      return in.readLine();
}
```

Comment: tryed this, same.. can't print anything out.

Comment: Well, Dear, we don't know how those methods are interleaved which each other in your code, so it could be more deep problem.

Comment: @IlendemliMuhammet This method doesn't print anything. Where are you expecting something to print?

Comment: I suspect the problem is you have no way of know from the way you send messages when a message stops.  This means you must read until you *close* the connection which you are not doing.  If you don't want to wait until you close you need to add some way of knowing when a message is finished e.g. a newline.

Comment: This Method returns a String, i am printing it somewhere else out. The Problem is while reading the Reader (r.read(buffer)).. but I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: @IlendemliMuhammet I have added a solution above. It will simplify your code.

Comment: Thank you.. I implemented this.. and it actually worked. but the problem seems to be somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you [`commons-io`](http://commons.apache.org/io/)  library for doing such things in a more convenient and simple way.
Just use:

`return IOUtils.toString(tempSocket.getInputStream());`

But this is only a code-style notice. We don't understand what do you mean by the term *getting a memory heap*. In any case, if you have insufficient memory troubles, you have to increase the memory for you Java application: [Memory Management in the Java
HotSpot™ Virtual Machine](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/memorymanagement-whitepaper-150215.pdf):

> **Java heap space** This indicates that an object could not be allocated
>   in the heap. The issue may be just a configuration problem. You could
>   get this error, for example, if the maximum heap size specified by the
>   –Xmx command line option (or selected by default) is insufficient for
>   the application. It could also be an indication that objects that are
>   no longer needed cannot be garbage collected because the application
>   is unintentionally holding references to them. The HAT tool (see
>   Section 7) can be used to view all reachable objects and understand
>   which references are keeping each one alive. One other potential
>   source of this error could be the excessive use of finalizers by the
>   application such that the thread to invoke the finalizers cannot keep
>   up with the rate of addition of finalizers to the queue. The jconsole
>   management tool can be used to monitor the number of objects that are
>   pending finalization.

Comment: tryed the commons-io but i don't get any message

Comment: Try to debug or add printout of variable `action` in method `sendServerMessage`.

Comment: sendServerMessage actually works, because I can give the Strings out with my Method with the char-Array.. the only Problem is, it is not efficient.